Grsync : synchronize two data hard drives already identical
I have two identical hard drives :

HDD1 (main)  : for common use
HDD2 (back up) : for back up

I would like to keep HDD2(back up) identical to HDD1(main), without beginning by erasing everything on HDD2(back up), then copy again HDD1(main) to HDD2(back up).
Is it possible with Grsync or any other ?
If not, does it means that after re-install my os in few years, I will have to erase again HDD2 (back up), to copy again HDD1 on it ?
Thanks a lot for your help !

I’m not 100% clear what you want to do. If you want an exact copy of hdd1 on hdd2, rsync can create a clone (byte by byte) of hdd1 on hdd2 - but it will overwrite anything on hdd1. You don’t need to separately wipe hdd2 before you start. You can then use rsync to maintain the clone as contemporaneous. This probably isn’t the most efficient way to backup - there’s plenty of data you probably don’t need to keep copies of. When you change os, you’ll have to start again.
